# ClassNotFoundException in java with mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jcreator

Good Day! Im having a problem in my mysql-connector-java.jar. I don't know if this is right, so here's the issue. I add the mysql-connector-java.jar in required libraries in my project. Here's the screen shot of that. then I call it in my class like this;

```
try
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    //My other code goes here

}
catch(SQLException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

[image]

I am getting the error of `ClassNotFoundException`. Im using Jcreator Pro.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you see jdbc jar exist inside your project ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir. I do not have the jdbc jar inside my project sir

Comment: You are using Eclipse without knowing how it works.  You must have the JAR available in the CLASSPATH when you compile and run, inside or outside the IDE.  Don't be one of those people who will next come back and say "Works in Eclipse, but not outside it."

Comment: Thanks for your help and suggestios. The day that i posted this question, i found out that my error is in my url from mysql. Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to do `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

Make sure that your `mysql-connector-java.jar` is in your classpath.

Comment: But in your question you have mentioned `myprojectname.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: Sir @Trying i have few more questions. Im very new to java, sorry for that.  Where can i paste the mysql-connector-java.jar in my jcreator or in java folder so whenever i created a project with database i can easily locate it.

Comment: in your project make a folder with name `lib` and keep all library/jar files in it and add them to class path.

Comment: @NeilMarvinEnriquez You can check this: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/connecting-to-mysql-using-jdbc-driver/

Comment: Thanks for your help and suggestios. The day that i posted this question, i  found out that my error is in my url from mysql. Thanks a lot guys